# Prove that $(a, \infty) \subseteq [b, \infty) \iff a \ge b$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, inequality, proof-verification

This is [exercise 10 - Problems II](https://books.google.com/books?id=ImCSX_gm40oC&pg=PA116) - of the book *"Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning"* by Peter J. Eccles.

> We define half-infinite intervals as follows:
>   \begin{align}
> (a, \infty) & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | x \gt a\} \\
> [a, \infty) & = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | x \ge a\} \\
> \end{align}
>
> Prove that $(a, \infty) \subseteq [b, \infty) \iff a \ge b$

I would like to confirm that my proof is indeed correct. In particular, I'm concerned with the first part (on the necessity of $a \ge b$).

Proof of $\Rightarrow$: Suppose that $(a, \infty) \subseteq [b, \infty)$. Then for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \in (a, \infty) \implies x \in [b, \infty)$, i.e. $x \gt a \implies x \ge b$. 
$\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{It\ follows\ that\ a\ \ge\ b.\ }$ But $(a, \infty) \subseteq [b, \infty) \implies [a, \infty) \subseteq [b, \infty)$, so that $a \in [a, \infty) \implies a \in [b, \infty)$ and we have $a \ge b$ as required.

Proof of $\Leftarrow$: Conversely, let $a \ge b$. Then given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \gt a \implies x \gt b$ and so certainly $x \ge b$.
Thus $(a, \infty) \subseteq [b, \infty)$ as required.
$\tag*{$\square$}$

---

**EDIT:**

I've improved the proof of $\Rightarrow$ as best as I can following the advice I was given, both in comments and answers.

However, I would appreciate if someone could demonstrate $(a, \infty) \subseteq [b, \infty) \implies [a, \infty) \subseteq [b, \infty)$ without using pictures, as that was the only way I could see it was true.

Thank you.

Comment: The proof of $\implies$ is not at all clear, because $a$ is not an element of $(a,+\infty)$.

Comment: Your first part still contains a small mistake. One cannot directly assume from $x>a \Rightarrow x\ge b$ that $a\ge b$. Try saying that $(a,\infty)\subseteq[b,\infty)$ implies $[a,\infty)\subseteq[b,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you! I will work that out and come back later with a proposed fix.

Comment: This is like a *perfect* question; it's exactly what we expect. Totally disagree with the downvoter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, show that $a<b\implies (a,\to)\not \subset [b,\to).$  Observe that $$a<b \implies a<(a+b)/2<b \implies (a+b)/2 \in (a,\to)\; \backslash  \;[b,\to).$$

Comment: Thank you, It didn't go through my mind to prove the contrapositive...

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of perfect completeness, you might want to show why $x > a \Rightarrow x \geq b$ implies that $a > b$.

Comment: Appreciated. I will try to do so and come back later with a proposed fix.